# Shiny Apps on using BLS API

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to import BLS data using library(RJSONIO). 
The imported data is in the data frame, which I am able to plot using ggplot.

I am not able to convert the codes into a shiny apps.

Please guide me.

**Server.R**

```
library(shiny)    
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
library(ggplot2)

bls.content <- getURLContent("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CES6056132001")




bls.json <- fromJSON(bls.content, simplify=TRUE)
tmp <-bls.json$Results[[1]][[1]]
bls.df <- data.frame(year=sapply(tmp$data,"[[","year"),
                     period=sapply(tmp$data,"[[","period"),
                     periodName=sapply(tmp$data,"[[","periodName"),
                     value=as.numeric(sapply(tmp$data,"[[","value")), 
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)





bls.df[bls.df$periodName!="Annual", ]

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$displot <- reactiveplot({
        ggplot(data=bls.df, aes(x=year, y=value, group=period)),
        gg <- ggplot(data=bls.df, aes(x=year, y=value, group=period)), 
        gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", aes(fill=period)),
        gg


  })

})
```

****UI.R****

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("BLS data"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("dataset", "Commodity:",
                ))),


mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("commSelected")),

    verbatimTextOutput("CommodityTable"),

    plotOutput("CommodityPlot")
  ))
```

Comment: What Shiny version are you on? The function in the past few versions of Shiny to create a plot is `renderPlot`. You might just need to update Shiny.

Comment: I am using Shiny Server latest version Version 0.98.693.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong with your code the way it's written, I'll try and explain where the grossest mistakes are.

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("BLS data"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("dataset", "Commodity:",c(1,2)
    )),


  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("commSelected")),

    verbatimTextOutput("CommodityTable"),

    plotOutput("CommodityPlot")
  ))
)
```

Key issues were around:

- pageWithSidebar is deprecated - though it works.
- selectInput has three required elements, inputId, label and choices.  You don't have any choices supplied there.  It should be selectInput("dataset","Commodity:",...) where ... is the list of choices.  I'm not familiar with the data you're using here so I didn't take the time to plop in the correct list of choices.  If the list of choices is fixed then use the format I did, c(a,b,c,...) - if it's from your data you can reference something loaded in global.R (another file you could have) which might be akin to bls.df$Commodities.
- You had too many parenthesis after the sidebarPanel - you closed the whole shinyUI before you got to the mainPanel.  I moved the offending parenthesis to the end.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)    
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
library(ggplot2)

bls.content <- getURLContent("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CES6056132001")

bls.json <- fromJSON(bls.content, simplify=TRUE)
tmp <-bls.json$Results[[1]][[1]]
bls.df <- data.frame(year=sapply(tmp$data,"[[","year"),
                 period=sapply(tmp$data,"[[","period"),
                 periodName=sapply(tmp$data,"[[","periodName"),
                 value=as.numeric(sapply(tmp$data,"[[","value")), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$CommodityPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=bls.df, aes(x=year, y=value, group=period))
    gg <- ggplot(data=bls.df, aes(x=year, y=value, group=period)) 
    gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", aes(fill=period))
    gg    
  }) 
})
```

Key issues here were around:

- First and foremost - you didn't bind your graphical output to one of the inputs you specified in your ui.R.  You named your plotOutput "CommodityPlot" but you bound your graphic to displot.  Remember, your output must bind to your input.
- reactivePlot is deprecated - I switched it to renderPlot
- Within renderPlot you had a comma after each line of your ggplot.  Each of your lines was already a complete statement and so the commas broke the code.  I removed them.  Remember, in R, whenever code is within {} you don't need to terminate lines with a ; and lines are never terminated with a ,.

Now, I've debugged your code and it works for me (I'm running RStudio 0.98.978 with shiny version 0.10.1).  Your app here is still very incomplete - you have bound output for your verbatimTextOutput "CommodityTable" or your textOutput "commSelected" and your data doesn't even appear to have a commodity in it so I don't know what you're planning on selecting.  The documentation for shiny is fairly good - I would strongly recommend visiting [the Shiny gallery](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/) to see working examples of shiny apps and the code that drive them.